# How to use file_get_contents() behind the proxy?

Tags: php, apache, file-get-contents

When we use file_get_contents, what does PHP use to resolve the domain name (local DNS??).

I ask because I got this error:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://external-domain.com)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed
>   to open stream: A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to
>   respond. in C:\test.php on line 11

I managed to fix this exact error previously when I used `file_get_contents()` on an internal URL i.e. `http://localhost:9090`, the problem was that I didn't have a mapping of localhost to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file on my windows machine. After adding this, I was able to use `file_get_contents()` on internal URLs.

Can this be fixed in a similar way?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a DNS problem. What happens if you try some other external domain? Could this be a firewall issue?

Comment: Well, i fear thats a completely different matter, if its an external domain the DNS handling shouldn't be a problem, looks like the other site just has a problem to respond, did you try using curl?

Comment: The URL I am accessing is correct and can be accessed by the browser on the same server fine.

Comment: @Pekka - I can access google via the browser URL on the server and I tried it with file_get_contents and it came back with the same error.

Comment: @Abs what if you use the IP address of an external site?

Comment: @Pekka - Good idea, but it doesn't work via the IP either. I think the proxy server and the firewall needs to be questioned now as it can't be anything else?

Comment: Wondering why trying the IP wasn't the first thing done when putting 127.0.0.1 in your hosts file fixed the localhost issue. If you're still failing to connect when going via IP, then the issue likely lies with your own router. Once you leave your network, all HTTP requests look the same to the external server. It has no way of knowing if it was requested by PHP, a browser, or wget in shell. It just sees a request. If the request never arrives, it's not being allowed to leave your network. Check proxy settings and see if your router is blocking any ports that PHP uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you behind a proxy? If so, you'll need to tell PHP about it using
[stream_context_set_default](http://php.net/stream_context_set_default) or by passing a context created with [stream_context_create](http://php.net/stream_context_create) as the third param to [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents).

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, it was because the value of default_socket_timeout in php.ini was too small.

I would try doubling its value in your case to see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem (but file on same server) that took me hours to find out. This did the trick then:

```
$fileUrl = "http://selfDomain.com/file.txt";

//external path to local path fix
$fileUrl = str_replace($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"], $_SERVER["LOCAL_ADDR"], $fileUrl);
```

Comment: You sir, just helped me tremendously. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply Use this, Your problem solved.

```
file_get_contents("http://external-domain.com",true)
```